# does $n*E(1/\sum_{j=1}^nX_j)$ converge to the reciprocal of the mean?

Tags: probability

Assuming $X_j$ are iid and have non-zero expectation. The LLN says that $(1/n)\sum_{j=1}^nX_j\to E(X)$. Does it hold that $n*E(1/\sum_{j=1}^nX_j) = 1/E(X)$? If not, are there conditions where it holds?

Comment: Try using Jensen's inequality $$\mathbb{E}[g(X)]\geq g(\mathbb{E}[X])$$ on your second expression.

Comment: @epp The strict inequality could become equality in the limit.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes as $n\to\infty$ for $\mathrm{E}[X] = \theta \neq 0$.

Using the [delta method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method) with $g(\theta) = 1/\theta$, we have that as long as $\sqrt{n}[\bar{X}_n - \theta] \stackrel{d}{\to}\mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$ and $g'$ exists around $\theta$ it follows
$$ \sqrt{n}[g(\bar{X}_n) - g(\theta)] \stackrel{d}{\to}\mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2[g'(\theta)]^2)$$
So that $g(\bar{X}_n) = \dfrac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^nX_i}$ converges to $g(\theta) = 1/\theta = 1/\mathrm{E}[X]$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Your answer is for the sample average, while the question is about the expectation. It seems worth clarifying if you are on the same page.

Comment: This is convergence in probability or similar, whereas the OP was asking about convergence of the mean.